# How to acces data in JSON file directly?

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a searchfunction like this,

```
.controller('searchCtrl', [

  '$scope', 'movieService', 'createMovie', 'removeMovie', '$http', function($scope, movieService, createMovie, removeMovie,  $http) {

    $scope.search = function() {

      var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3';
      var service = '/search/movie';
      var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
      var search = $scope.searchquery
      var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
      var url = base + service + '?api_key=' + apiKey + search + '&callback=' + callback;

      $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

          if (status == 200) {
            $scope.movieList = data.results;
            console.log($scope.movieList)
          } else {
            console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
          }

        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
        });
    }
```

Which creates a JSON output [like this](http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=james%20bond%20spectre&callback=angular.callbacks._0). This is the JSON output of a searchquery of `James Bond Spectre`.

This is the inputfield users use to search for a movie title. When it changes it fires the `search` action which does the http request.

```
%input{"ng-change" => "search(searchquery)", "ng-model" => "searchquery", "ng-model-options" => "{ debounce: 500 }", :id => "search_input", :placeholder => "Search a movie!", "ng-keyup" => "clear_results()"}
```

And here is where I show the search results.

```
%ul#showresults
  %li.search_results{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movieList | orderBy:'-release_date'"}

    .addmovie{"ng-click" => "addMovie()"}
      %span
        Add Movie
    %img.poster{"ng-src" => "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{ movie.poster_path }}"}
    %span.movieID
      {{ movie.id }}
    %span.title
      {{ movie.original_title }}
    %span.release
      {{ movie.release_date }}
```

When a user clicks on the `.addmovie` element it fires the `addMovie` action,

```
$scope.addMovie = function() {

  createMovie.create({
    title: $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.title').text(),
    release_date: $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.release').text(),
    image: $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.poster').attr("src")
  }).then(init);
};
```

And now we are getting to the problem. The create action looks at the value of a element and then saves that to the database. But there is certain information like the ID of the movie that I don't want to show in the result, how do I acces that straight from the JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is inappropriate jQuery-like workflow. There's no justification for storing model data in DOM and reading it from there.

There may be cleaner ways to do this without using indexes at all (e.g. isolate list item in separate directive), but something like

```
  ...
  %li.search_results{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movieList | orderBy:'-release_date'"}
    .addmovie{"ng-click" => "addMovie($index)"}
  ...
```

and

```
$scope.addMovie = function(i) {
  var movie = $scope.movieList[i];
  createMovie.create({
    title: movie.title,
    ...
  }).then(init);
};
```

is acceptable, for starters.